# visualization of a neural network model using keras 1.2

Tags: python, keras

Following this [keras doc](https://keras.io/visualization/), I do below to visualize the model in my Mac

```
from keras.utils import plot_model
plot_model('model.h5', to_file='model.png')
```

But get error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model.py", line 219, in <module>
    plot_model('model.h5', to_file='model.png')
NameError: name 'plot_model' is not defined
```

I looked into internet and found a [possible solution](http://www.codesofinterest.com/2017/02/visualizing-model-structures-in-keras.html). But this doesn’t quite work.

For example I have graphviz installed at `/Users/MYNAME/miniconda3/envs/carnd-term1/lib/graphviz` instead of `<path to anaconda environment>\Library\bin\graphviz\` as mentioned in the possible solution. So I am not sure if I am adding the right path in the PATH variable

Also I need to modify the `<path to anaconda environment>\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\visualize_util.py` file but there is no `site-packages` directory inside the `lib` directory of my `miniconda3` environment.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using an outdated version of Keras. For Keras 1.2, the function call is `keras.utils.visualize_util.plot()`. Also you need to give a model object to this function, not the filename of it. Use `model = load_model('model.h5')` and provide this object to `visualize_util.plot()`.